# Signing an ActiveX control

Tags: activex

I did this before, but i completely forgot how to sign an activeX control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Digital Signing for ActiveX Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231196(VS.60).aspx) (MSDN)